# Need some help in making a interactive Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I wanted to make a Jtable that can interact with an input `JTextField` and several `JButtons`. I first read the information from the file like this:

```
public insertion_sort_and_binary(Scanner sc) {
    int counter = 0;
    setTitle("GamesList");
    setSize(600, 360);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(null);

    database = new Game[Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())];
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        Object[] temp = this.theSpliter(sc.nextLine());
        database[counter] = new Game((String)temp[0],(String)temp[1],(String)temp[2],(String)temp[3],(String)temp[4]);
        counter++;
    }
    sort_database();
```

therefore I made this array list storing all the information, and then it will make the Jtable.

However I recognized that I will not able to do what I wanted with just a Jtable, so I needed to create a AbstractTableModle. The problem is I totally unable to recognize the construction of a AbstractTableModle.

Here is the list I needed help with Jtable:
I needed to add a new row as the add button pressed, however it will be at the sorted spot which means it will not be at the end but some where that it supposed be by alphabetical order.

Also I need to remove a set row if I pressed the remove button, it will search by name.

PS: there is one thing I really don't want, which is setting the boundary by some auto methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i needed to add a new row as the add button pressed, however it will be at the sorted spot which means it will not be at the end but some where that it supposed be by alphabetical order.

JTable supports sorting of the TableModel. You do not need to do the sorting yourself.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). Inserted rows will be displayed at the appropriate spot based on the current sort of the table.